# Ubuntu 14.04 install on hardware with RAID

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, raid

I've just built a new machine using an ASUS Mobo with 8GB of RAM and set up RAID 10 with 4 new HDD. I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it and so far have tried to do so 3 times with no luck.

The installation seems to work fine but after it has finished it restarts and all I get is a black screen.

Is there something I am missing? I've completed the install on other machines before without issue I just never tried it on a machine with RAID set up.

Comment: related: [Can I install ubuntu 14.04 on my RAIDed desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/479379/can-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-my-raided-desktop).